# My ASP.NET application does not insert all record into SQL Server after deployed into IIS,but works fine in my local. How do I resolve the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have 2 000 records that I'm inserting into SQL Server using bulk copy, which works well when I run the application locally (all the 2000 rows will be inserted).

The problem starts when I deploy my application to IIS, the only record that will be inserted into SQL Server is half the number of all records that I have, meaning the deployed application will insert only 1000 records.

Please help me guys, how can I resolve the issue? Thank you in advance.

Below is the sample on how I insert data into my SQL Server table

```
public DataTable DatatableList()
{
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("surname", typeof(int));

        foreach (var record in tableDataList)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(name, surname);
        }

        return table;
}

public void  SaveRecord()
{
        DataTable dtList = DatatableList();

        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, null);

            connection.Open();
            bulk.BatchSize = 50 000;
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "Person";
            bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
            bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("surname", "surname");
            bulk.WriteToServer(dtList);
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to write `connection.Close()` in this code. This is what the `using` block is for; it guarantees the connection is closed immediately at the end of the block, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: So no errors? Also, if you only try to insert 1000 records do all of them go into the dB or just 500? Have you tried to increase the BulkCopyTimeout property to see if it is just running out of time?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks i removed the `connection.close()` but still i experience the same issue

Comment: @JM_  yes i don't get any errors, When i try to insert those 1000 records on my local application they can be successfully inserted but the application that i deployed will insert only the half. This will happen even if i replace the code from `SaveRecord()` with `foreach (var x in GetPeopleList())
            {
                var addPerson = new Person
                {
                    name= x.name
                    surname= x.surname
                };

                _db.Person.Add(addPerson);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }` still i get the same result.

Comment: And when you run it through the debugger how many records are returned from GetPeopleList()? Also, when you look at the records that are inserted is it the exact first 500 records from your source or is it say every other record from your source?

Comment: @JM_ the application is work fine the problem was on the SQL side, Thanks alot for trying to help me.